# Retain separate dataframe structure after feature selection on list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

The `df` is a list of dataframes; `y` represents each dataframe. After feature selection, I want to retain the features in each dataframe `mut_fs`, `mirna_fs` as separate output.

```
dfs = [mut, mirna, mrna_exp, meth, protein] 
df = pd.concat(dfs)

dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.iloc[:,-1:], prefix="category")
df = pd.concat([df, dummies], axis=1)
df.drop("category", axis=1, inplace=True)

X = df.iloc[:,:-5]
y = df.iloc[:,-5:]

mms = MinMaxScaler()
X_mms = pd.DataFrame(mms.fit_transform(X.values), columns=X.columns, index=X.index)
```

Feature selection:

```
min_features_to_select = 10
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
cv = KFold(5)

rfecv = RFECV(estimator=clf, step=5, cv=cv, scoring="accuracy", min_features_to_select=min_features_to_select, n_jobs=2)

X_transformed = rfecv.fit_transform(X_mms, y)

X_transformed = X_mms.loc[:, rfecv.get_support()]
```

Data:

`mut`

```
mut = pd.DataFrame({'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': {'KNL1': 0,
  'MEGF8': 0,
  'JMJD1C': 0,
  'FREM2': 0,
  'SPEN': 0},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-01A': {'KNL1': 0,
  'MEGF8': 0,
  'JMJD1C': 0,
  'FREM2': 0,
  'SPEN': 1},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': {'KNL1': 0,
  'MEGF8': 0,
  'JMJD1C': 0,
  'FREM2': 0,
  'SPEN': 0},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': {'KNL1': 0,
  'MEGF8': 0,
  'JMJD1C': 0,
  'FREM2': 0,
  'SPEN': 0},
 'category': {'KNL1': 'Mutation',
  'MEGF8': 'Mutation',
  'JMJD1C': 'Mutation',
  'FREM2': 'Mutation',
  'SPEN': 'Mutation'}})
```

`mirna`

```
mirna = pd.DataFrame({'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': {'hsa-miR-664a-3p': 2.460083880550082,
  'hsa-miR-1307-3p': 3.287550991864731,
  'hsa-miR-1976': 1.962887971659645,
  'hsa-miR-2355-5p': 2.352633477409978,
  'hsa-miR-3607-3p': 2.10690806575631},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-01A': {'hsa-miR-664a-3p': 2.54188890339199,
  'hsa-miR-1307-3p': 3.3404984273244107,
  'hsa-miR-1976': 1.584687245555564,
  'hsa-miR-2355-5p': 1.2258390661832212,
  'hsa-miR-3607-3p': 2.308760900404995},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': {'hsa-miR-664a-3p': 2.577934740987889,
  'hsa-miR-1307-3p': 3.196635506896576,
  'hsa-miR-1976': 0.7959878740242344,
  'hsa-miR-2355-5p': 1.971638052906995,
  'hsa-miR-3607-3p': 2.0907950222445617},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': {'hsa-miR-664a-3p': 2.4871912626414576,
  'hsa-miR-1307-3p': 3.3312863379291127,
  'hsa-miR-1976': 1.964206800367793,
  'hsa-miR-2355-5p': 2.441762476705453,
  'hsa-miR-3607-3p': 2.004685616955679},
 'category': {'hsa-miR-664a-3p': 'miRNA',
  'hsa-miR-1307-3p': 'miRNA',
  'hsa-miR-1976': 'miRNA',
  'hsa-miR-2355-5p': 'miRNA',
  'hsa-miR-3607-3p': 'miRNA'}})
```

`mrna_exp`

```
mrna_exp = pd.DataFrame({'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': {'ZYG11B': 9.721558077351668,
  'ZYX': 13.149784472249904,
  'ZZEF1': 10.996463884857622,
  'ZZZ3': 9.5709146512422,
  'psiTPTE22': 8.39705036385952},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-01A': {'ZYG11B': 9.482960989216007,
  'ZYX': 12.18631415969286,
  'ZZEF1': 10.3849211071136,
  'ZZZ3': 9.630767657918822,
  'psiTPTE22': 3.155036774675642},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': {'ZYG11B': 9.991527373089331,
  'ZYX': 12.602417419256271,
  'ZZEF1': 10.4181662247631,
  'ZZZ3': 9.558068606793018,
  'psiTPTE22': 8.032538942350206},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': {'ZYG11B': 9.00642622908457,
  'ZYX': 13.08822035558983,
  'ZZEF1': 11.091529865870283,
  'ZZZ3': 7.709329928774525,
  'psiTPTE22': 4.55896554346589},
 'category': {'ZYG11B': 'mRNA',
  'ZYX': 'mRNA',
  'ZZEF1': 'mRNA',
  'ZZZ3': 'mRNA',
  'psiTPTE22': 'mRNA'}})
```

`meth`

```
meth = pd.DataFrame({'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': {'cg09560658': 0.939571238883928,
  'cg09560763': 0.494413413161009,
  'cg09560811': 0.9097565027488,
  'cg09560911': 0.031638387180189,
  'cg09560953': 0.851164164393655},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-01A': {'cg09560658': 0.929089720009317,
  'cg09560763': 0.301740989582562,
  'cg09560811': 0.920238344141844,
  'cg09560911': 0.0304795189432937,
  'cg09560953': 0.707673764192998},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': {'cg09560658': 0.932435869367479,
  'cg09560763': 0.235758339404136,
  'cg09560811': 0.924803871437567,
  'cg09560911': 0.0255867247450433,
  'cg09560953': 0.721923173082175},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': {'cg09560658': 0.910527920556733,
  'cg09560763': 0.731030638674928,
  'cg09560811': 0.929761655129724,
  'cg09560911': 0.0234602952079715,
  'cg09560953': 0.835676721188431},
 'category': {'cg09560658': 'Methylation',
  'cg09560763': 'Methylation',
  'cg09560811': 'Methylation',
  'cg09560911': 'Methylation',
  'cg09560953': 'Methylation'}})
```

`protein`

```
protein = pd.DataFrame({'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': {'p62-LCK-ligand': -0.85743991575,
  'p70S6K': 0.11706638225,
  'p70S6K_pT389': -0.20945653625,
  'p90RSK': -0.03276679775,
  'p90RSK_pT359_S363': -0.35120344275},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-01A': {'p62-LCK-ligand': 0.48058468225,
  'p70S6K': -0.34041949075,
  'p70S6K_pT389': 0.12322377375,
  'p90RSK': -0.17832512275,
  'p90RSK_pT359_S363': -0.0444110847500001},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': {'p62-LCK-ligand': -0.443653053,
  'p70S6K': 0.330332598,
  'p70S6K_pT389': 0.0048678305,
  'p90RSK': 0.373424473,
  'p90RSK_pT359_S363': -0.237274864},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': {'p62-LCK-ligand': 0.892347429,
  'p70S6K': -0.398764372,
  'p70S6K_pT389': 0.8054628965,
  'p90RSK': -0.039002197,
  'p90RSK_pT359_S363': 0.804770661},
 'category': {'p62-LCK-ligand': 'Protein',
  'p70S6K': 'Protein',
  'p70S6K_pT389': 'Protein',
  'p90RSK': 'Protein',
  'p90RSK_pT359_S363': 'Protein'}})
```

Expected output (example):

`mut_fs`

```
mut_fs = pd.DataFrame({'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': {'KNL1': 0,
  'MEGF8': 0,
  'FREM2': 0,
  'SPEN': 0},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': {'KNL1': 0,
  'MEGF8': 0,
  'FREM2': 0,
  'SPEN': 0},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': {'KNL1': 0,
  'MEGF8': 0,
  'FREM2': 0,
  'SPEN': 0},
 'category': {'KNL1': 'Mutation',
  'MEGF8': 'Mutation',
  'FREM2': 'Mutation',
  'SPEN': 'Mutation'}})
```

`mirna_fs`

```
mirna_fs = pd.DataFrame({'TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A': {'hsa-miR-664a-3p': 2.460083880550082,
  'hsa-miR-1307-3p': 3.287550991864731,
  'hsa-miR-1976': 1.962887971659645,
  'hsa-miR-3607-3p': 2.10690806575631},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A': {'hsa-miR-664a-3p': 2.577934740987889,
  'hsa-miR-1307-3p': 3.196635506896576,
  'hsa-miR-1976': 0.7959878740242344,
  'hsa-miR-3607-3p': 2.0907950222445617},
 'TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A': {'hsa-miR-664a-3p': 2.4871912626414576,
  'hsa-miR-1307-3p': 3.3312863379291127,
  'hsa-miR-1976': 1.964206800367793,
  'hsa-miR-3607-3p': 2.004685616955679},
 'category': {'hsa-miR-664a-3p': 'miRNA',
  'hsa-miR-1307-3p': 'miRNA',
  'hsa-miR-1976': 'miRNA',
  'hsa-miR-3607-3p': 'miRNA'}})
```

Comment: I get an error for `rfecv.fit_transform(X_mms, y)` -> `ValueError: Found array with 1 feature(s) (shape=(10, 1)) while a minimum of 2 is required by RFECV.`. Can you check it please?

Comment: @Corralien sorry for the confusion. `dfs` is a list of 5 dataframes and I now included sample data for each of them. The error you received might be because I omitted 3 of them from my example.

Comment: How do you know the expected output? For me all features are selected by `rfecv.get_support()`

Comment: I don't know the expected output. But just in case anyone is confused with my question, I added the "expected output" to emphasize that I want to retain separate dataframes. Maybe I should remove that part of my question. But yes, the features are selected from `rfecv.get_support()`.

Comment: Maybe matching the index of `X_transformed` to the original data frames might work

Comment: May I suggest you don't drop `category` column after `get_dummies`, it could be easier. I can show you if you want.

Comment: Ok you can show it. If I don't drop the `category` column, should it be in `y`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252254/discussion-between-corralien-and-melolili).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following our conversation, you can explode your `X_transformed` dataframe into a dictionary of dataframe whose keys are the category name:

```
# df.drop("category", axis=1, inplace=True)
cats = df.pop('category')

# Your feature selection

feats = rfecv.get_feature_names_out()[rfecv.get_support()]
groups = X_transformed[feats].groupby(cats, sort=False)
out = dict(list(g))
```

Output:

```
>>> out.keys()
dict_keys(['Mutation', 'miRNA', 'mRNA', 'Methylation', 'Protein'])

>>> out['Protein']
                   TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A  TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-01A  TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A  TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A
p62-LCK-ligand             0.000000          0.065540          0.000000          0.095730
p70S6K                     0.069572          0.000000          0.059327          0.000000
p70S6K_pT389               0.046261          0.037012          0.034380          0.089288
p90RSK                     0.058875          0.012940          0.062630          0.026675
p90RSK_pT359_S363          0.036141          0.023630          0.015819          0.089237

>>> out['Mutation']
        TCGA-Y8-A8RY-01A  TCGA-Y8-A8RZ-01A  TCGA-Y8-A8S0-01A  TCGA-Y8-A8S1-01A
KNL1            0.061214          0.027175          0.034007          0.029567
MEGF8           0.061214          0.027175          0.034007          0.029567
JMJD1C          0.061214          0.027175          0.034007          0.029567
FREM2           0.061214          0.027175          0.034007          0.029567
SPEN            0.061214          0.107005          0.034007          0.029567
```